# Azure Service Bus delayed (scheduled) message on Topic is lost when used with Duplicate Detection

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We are facing a problem with Service Bus.

1. We have a topic, with two subscriptions.
2. We have enabled Duplicate Detection on those,  with 1 minutes window (tried with 2 seconds first). We are using Duplicate Detection to avoid multiple messages processed in short interval  (to maintain the interval between the messages)
3. We are using the message scheduling (**ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc**) to repeat the messages to appear after 5 minutes, with same message ID (every time a new message is created with schedule, and old message is completed)
4. The workflow is as follows (**problem**):

   - First time a message is published (without scheduling)
   - This message is immediately consumed by the message pump, and a new message with same details and a schedule time of 5 minutes is send to the topic (UTC), expecting it to appear after 5 minutes
   - The message is not appearing in the subscription
5. When debugged, this issue doesn’t come up
6. When we send the **First** message with at least 30 second delay (scheduled), then it is working fine
7. If we recreate the topic and subscription with Duplicate Detection turned off, we are able to get the message using the above workflow

Since we have no clue on what is happening to the published message, we need help to identify the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior of the ASB.
When a message is scheduled, it's actually enqueued on the broker with delayed appearance. ASB on the server side de-duplicates messages upon arrival and uses message ID for de-dup.

In your case, if you delay dispatch of the second message and the original message is processed, there will be nothing to de-dup and the second message will be enqueued. If you don't delay, then the broker will see an identical ID to the previously sent message that has not been completed or DLQed yet, and it will be de-duped.

Possible way to go about is **not** reuse the same transport message ID (ID used for the `BrokeredMessage`). In case you need to associate messages, you can use `Properties` for that.

Comment: Partially explains the behavior. so I will mark it as answer. But still the point 6 in the original question not properly explained

Comment: If you can provide a link to a reproduction code, I'd be able to help on that specific point.